# SyntaxError: Parse error in html map file - ogmaps ReferenceError: Can't find variable: GUnload

Tags: c++, html, qt, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The link to the full html `ogmap` map code: http://code.google.com/p/earthhtml/source/browse/trunk/ogmap.html

This map file opens from all browsers *(after minimizing and maximizing the browser once)*,
but
**When it try to execute it from my C++ code as follows:**

```
void MainScreen::on_button1_clicked()
{
    map->clearCoordinates();
    map->load(QUrl("file:///home/anisha/Desktop/fwdgooglemaps/ogmaps/ogmap.html"));
}
```

**following error is shown:**

```
"SyntaxError: Parse error on line:1148 Source:file:///home/anisha/Desktop/fwdgooglemaps/ogmaps/ogmap.html"

"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: GUnload on line:186 Source:file:///home/anisha/Desktop/fwdgooglemaps/ogmaps/ogmap.html"
```

Line number 1148 is shown here.

```
function preloadRasterTile (uris,tile,zoom,x,y,transparent,htmlList)
{
    var url = getTileUrl (uris,tile,zoom);
    transparent&&/MSIE 6/i.test (navigator.userAgent)?
    htmlList.push(['<div style="left:', 256*x, "px;top:", 256*y, "px;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader (sizingMethod = crop, src = '", url, '"', '__src__ = "'+url+'"', "></div>"].join ("")) : htmlList.push (['<img style = "position:absolute; left:',256*x," px="px">'].join(""))
}
```

EDIT:

I just commented the line 186, the reference error is gone, but the syntax error is still there.
There is no browser involved. **I am loading this cached map on the qt widget.**

**EDIT 2:**

---

The code is now showing another error on this line: 
`else if (0 < minzoom><widthinearthunits><heightinearthunits><actions.length>;i++)`

in function `repositionInlineZoomControls`.

**index.html file for the javascript is as follows:**

Google Maps JavaScript API Example

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var map;    
var latlng            = new google.maps.LatLng (28.635308, 77.22496);

var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer ();
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService ();

var pointsArray       = new Array();
var arrayToBeReturned = new Array();

function initialize ()
{
    var myOptions = 
    {
        zoom:4,
        center:latlng,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map (document.getElementById ("map"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap (map); 
    }

    function addMarker (x, y)
{
    var initialPoint       = new google.maps.LatLng (x, y);
    var initialPointMarker = new google.maps.Marker ({
                                position:initialPoint,
                                map:map,
                                draggable:false,
                                flat:true
                                });
}

 var arrayMarkers = new Array();
var arrayIndex   = 0;

function Open(x, y)
{   var newPosition = new google.maps.LatLng (x, y);
    map.setCenter (newPosition);        

    directionsDisplay.setMap (map);


    google.maps.event.addListener (map, "click", 
                            function (event)
                            {
                                //alert("You clicked the map."+ event.latLng.toString(4));

                                arrayMarkers [arrayIndex] = event.latLng;

                                var s0  = event.latLng.lat();
                                var s1  = event.latLng.lng();
                                var s01 = new google.maps.LatLng (s0, s1);

                                var point1 = new google.maps.Marker ({
                                                                position:arrayMarkers [arrayIndex],
                                                                draggable:false,
                                                                map:map,
                                                                flat:true
                                                                }); 
                                if (arrayIndex == 1)
                                    displayRoute ();

                                arrayIndex++;
                            });

}

function displayRoute ()
 {
    var start = arrayMarkers [0];
    var end   = arrayMarkers [1];

    var request = {
                origin:start,
                destination:end,
                travelMode:google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                };

    directionsService.route (request, 
                        function (result, status) 
                        {
                            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
                            {
                                directionsDisplay.setDirections (result);

                                pointsArray = result.routes[0].overview_path;

                                var i = 0;
                                var j = 0;

                                for (j = 0; j < pointsArray.length; j++)
                                {                                       
                                    arrayToBeReturned [i] = pointsArray[j].lat ();
                                    i++;
                                    arrayToBeReturned [i] = pointsArray[j].lng ();
                                    i++;

                                    var point1 = new google.maps.Marker ({
                                        position:pointsArray[j],
                                        draggable:false,
                                        map:map,
                                        flat:true
                                        });
                                }
                            }
                        });


    getCoordinates();
}

function getCoordinates ()
{       
    return arrayToBeReturned;
}

</script> 
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<div id="map" style="width: 641px; height: 671px"></div>
<div id="directionsPanel" style="float:right;width:1000%;height 100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What language is this? C++ perhaps? What is your "map" object? Is it a web browser that can load HTML pages and execute Javascript? In any case, GUnload is from the V2 api, which has been deprecated for some time now. It does not exist in the API V3. (current version)

Comment: @Marcelo Actually I am doing all this on a Qt widget. the map is loaded on the Qt widget, this is c++. What is the solution here?

Comment: I have no idea what the solution is, but I'd suggest re-tagging the question with "Qt" and "C++" so that people with relevant expertise can find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That htmlList.push line at least looks a bit fishy, particularly use of quotes does not seem correct to me. It seems that single quotes and double quotes are mixed somewhere. For example src parameter passed to AlphaImageLoader starts with single quote, but ends with double quote.

In general it is a good idea to remain consistent in using quotes even though it is possible to use both double and single quotes. That will help in the long run.

I would probably go with a bit more verbose, but more readable function. I tried to fix the quoting issues:

```
function preloadRasterTile (uris,tile,zoom,x,y,transparent,htmlList) 
{
    var url = getTileUrl (uris,tile,zoom);
    if (transparent && /MSIE 6/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        htmlList.push([
            '<div style="left:', 256*x, 'px;',
            'top:', 256*y, 'px;',
            'filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader (sizingMethod = crop, src = "', url, '"', '__src__ = "'+url+'"', 
            '></div>'].join (""));
    } else {
        htmlList.push([
            '<img style = "position:absolute;',
            'left:', 256*x, 'px;">'].join(""));
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't written that code. I am not well versed in html. Please think about correcting that code if you think that's wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Edited the answer to contain code of preloadRasterTile function.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped in that error getting solved. Now, it is showing error on this line: `else if (0 < minzoom><widthinearthunits><heightinearthunits><actions.length>;i++)` in function `repositionInlineZoomControls`. That's a strange way of writing a if statement. Haven't seen such things in C. BTW, if this html file contains so many errors then how does it get displayed in a browser?

Comment: What is that function supposed to do and have you written that yourself? How does it work in browser?

Comment: Oh, I thought I had clarified this in the first post. This html file is a map which I have downloaded from `ogmaps` software. When I open this in a browser, the map gets displayed. But when I try to load this on a qt widget the Google map's javascript API throw errors.

Comment: Yep, but I tried it on browsers and from what I can see, it certainly does not work. Firefox shows some errors in error console and IE seems to render something that I can't see slightly off from the window top...

Comment: @Jare, :) try maximizing and then restoring your browser, it'll work.

Comment: also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344516/cached-google-map-shows-up-initially-small-in-a-browser :) :) same file.

Comment: No it did not. And even if it did, I wouldn't call it working still... There is certainly something wrong in the code, plus it is compacted in a way that makes it really hard to follow and understand.

Comment: yes I realize that the code is complicated. It doesn't seem to be written by a human. I think I should dump this html file and download some else map which doesn't show these errors. BTW, for me, it works by minimizing and maximizing browser.