# Cached Google Map shows up initially small in a browser

Tags: linux, qt, google-maps

This is a cached map from the software: `ogmaps`

Please look carefully at the tiny shades below the address bar in the main window here.
[image]

On once clicking the minimize/maximize button, it gets showed up fully. Tested on firefox, and google chrome.

**Can't say that this is the browser problem, since when I loaded this cached map on the Qt widget, I still had to click the minimize/maximize button, to get it gets showed up fully.**

[image]

The html for the map is too long to be posted here. If there is any relevant section that you know of, then please tell me and I'll post it here.

EDIT 2

Finally I have managed to upload that html code here: http://code.google.com/p/earthhtml/source/browse/trunk/ogmap.html

Please have a look about the `div` tags.

Comment: Looks like a size problem on the map div.  How about posting the part of your code that sets the height and the width?

Comment: @geocodezip is probably correct. This is the problem I usually see when I forget to size the map div. Are you doing it like so: `<div id="map_canvas" style="width:someValue; height:someOtherValue"></div>`?

Comment: @geocodezip have added the div info. is there something else that i need to add?

Comment: @EliHooten please look into the quetsion now. Anything els eshould i add?

Comment: What is the name of the map div? How is the size of the div containing the map div set?

Comment: @geocodezip thanks for following up. I am not well versed in html. I have uploaded the html code in the link, please have a look about the div tags. Edited the question.

Comment: Your page is very difficult to read, if you post a link to the page someone could look at it in a browser and answer the question quickly.   Another suggestion would be to run it through an html validator.

Comment: Seconding @geocodezip. It's really hard for me to see where the appropriate contents to create the Google Map are. You're calling `someVar = new google.maps.Map(someDiv, someOptions)`, or something like it, somewhere, right? Can you point out where that is, maybe include it in your question? A search/perusal of your code didn't turn it up for me. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the page you provided: http://code.google.com/p/earthhtml/source/browse/trunk/ogmap.html it looks like the "source view" of this https://maps.google.com/maps?q=plano,+tx&hl=en&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=52.902929,77.34375&hnear=Plano,+Collin,+Texas&t=m&z=12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this may seem like something trivial, it worked out for me. I had the exact same problem (among other GM problems) using GMv3 and couldn't figure it out.

- I **added** a `min-height` to the div containing the map (with `!important`)
- I **removed** ALL `max-height & max-widths` from the CSS

This fixed the 'small map' problem plus an additional problem I had with the GM pins and infowindows.

On top of that, make sure that there are NO divs with a high `z-index` on your page, as GM will resize the containing div not to interrupt with the top div. Another div with a higher `z-index` will also mess up the map and make the height and the width go crazy.

```
div#map{
min-height:600px !important; /* or any value that suits you */
position:relative;
margin-left:0;
margin-right:0;
left:0;
border:1px solid #979797;
}
```

I hope this works as good for you as it worked for me. If not, good luck!